# Why does the back() function in Python's turtle module not work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

```
edge = 120
angle = 120
pendown()
# penup()
back(edge // 2)
# print(heading())
# left(90)
# why can't use forward ?? the direction is 
opposite?
back(math.sin(60) * edge // 2)
# right(90)
# print(pos())
# drawhexagram("blue","red",edge)
mainloop()
```

When I use turtle in python, I tried two commands `back(edge // 2)` and `back(math.sin(60) * edge // 2)` but when I ran the code, the second command let the turtle head go forward instead of going backward. I can't understand why it happened?

Comment: Note that `math.sin` takes **radians** not degrees.. Are you sure you want `math.sin(60)`? and not `math.sin(2/3.0 * math.pi)`?

Comment: The turtle had grown up and is choicing his own decisions

Answer (score 0):

`math.sin` wants *radians* not degrees:

```
>>> math.sin(60)
-0.3048106211022167
>>> math.sin(2/3.0*math.pi)
0.8660254037844387
>>>
```

As you can see you passed a negative number to `back` and thus it went in the opposite direction of what you thought.